# Toggle doesn't work, show only one item

Tags: javascript, jquery

My toggle doesn't work, guess it is because of the this find but its outside the toggle-it?
I have multiple items with the same classes but they don't need to slide open all just one.

```
<div class="te">
    <span class="da">datum<span class="toggle-it">more info</span></span><br>
    <span class="be">beschrijving</span>
    <div class="show-more" style="display:none;">Bla bla info</div>
</div>


$('.toggle-it').click(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.show-more').slideDown(250);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.show-more').slideUp(250);
    }
);
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/nfxesod3/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.click()` function only accepts one function argument. Also, you need to use `.closest()` to traverse up the DOM first, and then `.find()` to go back down. You can do this instead:

```
$('.toggle-it').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.te').find('.show-more').slideToggle(250);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nfxesod3/2/)**

Comment: Question: do you have any idea why I need to add the code after the div? When I add it in the <head> it don't work.

Comment: Because unless your code in the head is in a `$( document ).ready()`, the elements you are referring to don't yet exist, so you're trying to execute code on something that hasn't been encountered yet. See also http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/